# How to find Mac admin password not reset Mac admin password

Tags: macos, mac, administrator

I am not a administrator and I would like to find the administrator password. I would not like to reset it however. Is there anyway to find and not reset the administrator password?

Comment: If it were that easy what would be the point of having one?

Comment: What is it you're trying to do that you need the Admin password?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because is about Hacking passwords.

Comment: @Buscar웃 - actually, I'm voting to leave it open as a lesson to be learned, for any future Googlers.

Answer (score 6):

That's the point of the security on a computer : Without the admin password don't expect to do much, this includes getting the admin password.

[#Ouroboros](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ouroboros).

Comment: LOL @ Ouroboros ;-) Catch-22 too.

Answer (score 1):

OS X does not store a plain-text copy of your administrator password. This makes it impossible to have the computer show you the existing password.

OS X can only test if an attempted password is the administrator password.

OS X has no way to show you the original. The original is immediately thrown away when the password is set; only a hash of the password is kept.

## Why? Hashed Passwords

Passwords are stored as [mathematically derived hashes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function) of the original. This hash makes it possible to determine if an attempted password matches the real password, but it also makes it impossible to determine the real password.